# Remove Duplicated Entries From an Array

Tags: php

For removing the duplicated entries I know I have to use `array_unique()` but unfortunately by using this I got unexpected result(s). My PHP code is this:

```
    $query = $db->query("
SELECT sid,father_contact,residential_contact
FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."student_list
{$where_clause}
ORDER BY sid ASC");
while ($s = $db->fetch_array($query))
{
    if (!empty($s['father_contact']))
    {
        $father_contact = $s['father_contact'].', ';
    }
    else
    {
        $father_contact = '';
    }

    if (!empty($s['residential_contact']))
    {
        $residential_contact = $s['residential_contact'].', ';
    }
    else
    {
        $residential_contact = '';
    }

    $phone_nums_bit .= $father_contact.$residential_contact;
}
```

This grabs all phone numbers from the database tables and print the result like this:

```
03334523675, 03124237009, 03134237002, 03124237009, 03217832173, 03134237002, 3134237002, 03124237009,
```

Notice that few numbers like `03134237002` is repeating thrice. I want to remove duplicate entries from this result. Please help me to sort it out. Thanks.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: @JayBlanchard: Tried that too, but unfortunately it doesn't helped.

Comment: When you say you get unexpected results. Exactly what results do you get? I don't see `array_unique()` anywhere in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do it via array structures. Just to give you an idea:

```
$phones = [];
while ($s = $db->fetch_array($query))
{
    if (!empty($s['father_contact']))
    {
        $phones[] = $s['father_contact'];
    }

    if (!empty($s['residential_contact']))
    {
        $phones[] = $s['residential_contact'];
    }
}
$phones = array_unique($phones);
// and then combine into string
$phone_nums_bit = implode(', ', $phones);
```